# How do I enable autocomplete on fields inside tableselect

Tags: ajax

I have form which outputs tableselect. 
The tableselect have many textfields which should be autocomplete.

The problem is that textfields never become autocomplete fields and even form_process_autocomplete doesn't called.

```
/**
 * implements hook_overview_form
 */
function supplier_overview_form(&$form, Supplier $supplier) {
  $header = array(
    'supplier_data' => array('data' => t('Supplier data')),
    'vocabulary' => t('Vocabulary'), 
    'term' => t('System Term'),
  );

  $query = db_select('supplier_data_mapping', 'sdm')
  ->fields('sdm')
    ->condition('supplier', $supplier->machine_name)
    ->orderBy('system_term', 'ASC');

  $result = $query->execute();

  $options = array();

  $title_field = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Supplier data'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#value' => '',
    '#name' => 'supplier_data'
  );
  $vocabularies = array();

  $vocs = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
  foreach ($vocs as $key => $info) {
    $vocabularies[$info->machine_name] = t($info->name);
  }

  $vocabulary_field = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $vocabularies,
    '#title' => t('Select Vocabulary'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#name' => 'voc'
  );

  $term_field = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Term'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#name' => 'term',
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'term-autocomplete', 'class' => array('supplier-mapping-autocomplete')),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'admin/supplier/term-autocomplete/265',
    '#default_value' => '',
  );

  while ($record = $result->fetchObject()) {
   $options[$record->mapping_id] = array(
    'supplier_data' => array('data' => $title_field),
    'vocabulary' => array('data' => $vocabulary_field),
    'term' => array('data' => $term_field),
   );

   $options[$record->mapping_id]['supplier_data']['data']['#title'] = t('Delete');
   $options[$record->mapping_id]['supplier_data']['data']['#name'] .= '[' . $record->mapping_id . ']';
   $options[$record->mapping_id]['supplier_data']['data']['#value'] = $record->supplier_data;

    $options[$record->mapping_id]['vocabulary']['data']['#value'] = $record->system_vocabulary;
    $options[$record->mapping_id]['vocabulary']['data']['#name'] .= '[' . $record->mapping_id . ']';

    if (!empty($record->system_term)) {
     $term = taxonomy_term_load($record->system_term);
     if ($term) {
         $options[$record->mapping_id]['term']['data']['#value'] = $term->name . ' ('.$term->tid.')';
      }
    }

   $options[$record->mapping_id]['term']['data']['#attributes']['id'] = 'term-autocomplete-' . $record->mapping_id;
   $options[$record->mapping_id]['term']['data']['#id'] = 'term-autocomplete-' . $record->mapping_id;
     //$options[$record->mapping_id]['term']['data']['#autocomplete_path'] .=  '/' . $record->system_vocabulary;
     $options[$record->mapping_id]['term']['data']['#name'] .=  '[' . $record->mapping_id . ']';
 }

  $form['maps'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
    //'#attached' => array('js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'terp_supplier_data_map') . '/js/terp_supplier_data_map.js')),
  );
  $form['supplier'] = array(
   '#type' => 'value',
     '#value' => $supplier->machine_name,
  );
}
```

Comment: Is the path **admin/supplier/term-autocomplete/265** valid and does it return a JSON string?

Comment: Hi Patrick. The autocomplete path is valid, but the issue is not autocomplete_path. The render function doesn't even call form_process_autocomplete, where actually checked is element is authocomplete and url is valid or not.

Comment: Have you checked [theme_textfield](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7)? Do you get through the autocomplete_path check?

Comment: Yes, theme_textfield called after form_process_autocomplete where checked #autocomplete_input and returns output. The issue is that form_process_autocomplete is not called.

Comment: You keep repeating that the issue is that form_process_autocomplete is not called. However, this function is only a workaround for clean URLs. You can add it by yourself with **'#process' => array('form_process_autocomplete', 'ajax_process_form'),** I think something else is going wrong, do you have any Javascript errors? Is autocomplete.js included?

Comment: Even adding #process to textfield it doesn't work. I'm repeating saying that 'form_process...' is not called, as most important part done there, and after it theme_textfield. I don't have any js related issue.

Comment: There is a seems very strange behavior. If I change theme from seven to Bootstrap based sub-theme it started work, while on themes which come with core it doesn't.

Comment: Thats strange indeed. Maybe you should compare the template.php of both themes and check if one of the theme functions is overriden or maybe some Javascript which disables something. It's hard to say what the problem is, but fortunately it's not in your code.